# ReCaptcha loading takes ages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, recaptcha

Loading recaptcha on dev site takes ages in Chrome, but works well in Firefox and Incognito window. I have no AdBlocker etc enabled.

The issue seems to be in a service worker. Can anyone point in a direction how to debug this?

https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1543818755456/recaptcha__en.js

[image: performance tree]